# Spring Data Mongo: upsert with various fields updated

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am searching for the right way to implement the *upsert* operation to a Mongo Collection using the API given by Spring Data.

In details, I have the following use case. The schema of the collection `collection` is something like the following:

```
{
  _id: "some_id",
  field1: "value1",
  field2: "value2",
  subdocument1: {
    // A subdocument with some fields
  },
  subdocument2: {
    // A subdocument with some other fields
  }
}
```

The fields `field1` and `field2` are always present, but `subdocument1` and `subdocument2` will be inserted in different moments: one during the first insertion, the second with a subsequent update.

I saw that `MongoTemplate` has and [upsert](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoTemplate.html#upsert-org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query-org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Update-java.lang.Class-) method. Using this method I have to build my own the update operation.

```
Query query = Query.query(Criteria.where("_id").is("some_id"));
Update.update("_id", "some_id")
      .set("field1", "value1")
      .set("field2", "value2")
      .set("subdocument1", subdocumentObject);
mongoTemplate.upsert(query, update, Collection.class);
```

I cannot understand if it is what I am searching for and if there is a better approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is `$setOnInsert` for `subdocument1`. So something like should work for you.

```
Query query = Query.query(Criteria.where("_id").is("some_id"));
Update update = Update.update("_id", "some_id")
                .set("field1", "value1")
                .set("field2", "value2")
                .set("subdocument2", subdocumentObject2)
                .setOnInsert("subdocument1", subdocumentObject1);
```

More here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/

Comment: Thanks for the `setOnInsert` method, I miss it. I will use it for `field1`, `field2`. Unfortunately I do not know _a priori_ if `subdocument1` or `subdocument2` will arrive first.

Comment: You don't have to use `setOnInsert` for `field1` and `field2` as they are always  present. You should just continue using `set` for those fields. You can write a conditional statement something like   `if("somecriteria") {
            update.set("subdocument2" ... )
        } else
            update.setOnInsert("subdocument1" ... )`

Comment: I do not understand why you are proposing a different approach for `subdocument1` and `subdocument2`. Can you argue this fact?

Comment: Sure because I thought one you wanted only on insert and the other one as part of update No ? I'm just trying to see if there is logic that you have on your side which drives that. It can be any document but you have to know whether you want to insert or update and pass that document to the applicable operator.

Comment: Actually I am using `set` only on subdocument that I know it is not empty. Will using `setOnInsert` on other field improve the performances?

Comment: I don't think its related to performance. If the query criteria that you have results in `upsert` then the upsert operation will merge the fields from both `set` and `setOnInsert` and insert a  document into database. If it results in `update` it will only use fields from `set`. So you can use them to drive shape of your document.